# Converting a SQL DataBase to a PDF document

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I'm hoping someone can help here, I have been following a great tutorial, http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/04/sqlite-example-in-android-add-image.html

This allows me a create a List of photos taken from the gallery or the camera.

What i would love to be able to do is convert / write that data to a PDF document which i can save to the SD card.

I've hunted around the net and have really, really struggled to find any decent tutorials....

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated

Regards

Will

Comment: I didn't understand a thing: you want to display all those data also in a pdf saved on the SD card or save the SQL Database on this pdf?

Comment: I want to be able to transfer the data that is collected by the database to a PDF